# How to run background process code using django?

Tags: django, django-views, background-task

I'm working with `django-background-task` package for the first time. I've tried to follow the docs and create a sample background task file - the task itself is working fine.

But I can't figure out how to configure **schedule time** and **repeat time** properly: when I set interval **time=10s** it keeps running every second. How to fix it?

**My Code**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=5)
def hello():
    print("Hello World!")


def index(request):
    hello(repeat=10)
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello World</h1>')
```