# How to subscribe to GCP Pub/Sub when running a server of Django?

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a backend service using django, I need to subscribe a message queue hosted on GCP pub/sub

Here's the example code provided by Google:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull

Implementing a function is easy,

but I will have to start the django server via the command like:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Or ASGI commands

This subscribing function should be running continuously, better in the background,

How can I achieve this?

I have tried django-crontab or django-background-task, but either of these needs to run commands manually, I don't think this is what I need.

Comment: If you want to use pull subscription, you will need to extend django to run a continuous background task (eg. using django-background-task https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Imo the easier/natural way is to use push subscription https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push

Comment: @YohanesGultom But django-background-task seems have to run via the command  `python manage.py process_task ` . Can I use this package with runserver?

Comment: Well, technically you can, by using subprocess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172183/can-i-run-a-background-process-in-django-without-starting-a-parallel-process. But it will be easier to just run `python manage.py process_task` as a separate command/process (also mentioned in the link above)

Comment: Where do you want to run your django code? According to the underlying platform, the answers are different

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am using GCP GKE, docker.

Comment: If you are on GKE, start a pod with your Django server. At startup start your pulling process. What's your problem with this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have a docker command in my docker file like this: `CMD gunicorn myapp.asgi:application --bind :8000  --workers 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`. Do I have to change this into something ?

Comment: I don't know. To be sure, you should share a piece of code to guide you more precisely. Additionally, I have a design problem with what you want to achieve: you have a webserver that answers to HTTP request AND a background task that pull the messages in the same service. Did you think to redesign your app? (if possible)

Comment: @AndyHuang did you ever figure out a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Add new process as below format in Django

```
taskApp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            task_process.py
```

In startup.sh add below command

```
#!/bin/sh
gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker myapplication.asgi:application & python manage.py task_process
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
    gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker myapplication.wsgi:application & python manage.py task_process
```

In Dockerfile call this at last

```
RUN chmod +x startup.sh
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

To check whether processing running or not you can verify as below

```
ps -ef | grep task_process
```